# WCF process-is-terminated-due-to-stackoverflowexception

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf

when i run a method within my WCF service i get "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in developer1SVC.dll".

No infinite loops exist and no infinite recursion is occurring. Any ideas to why this may be happening? when i run the method through wcf test client. I get the results back correctly however, hooking it up to my console app and running it breaks the application. The other methods run fine. It is this one method. Just trying to get the feel for WCF services. The service breaks right after i return accounts from the "generateMultiplAccounts" method.

Much help appreciated.

Service

```
using developer1.Core.ServiceContracts;
using developer1.Core.Data;
using developer1.Core.Dto;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using developer1.Core.Dto.Account;

namespace developer1.Core.Service
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
    // NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select Service1.svc or Service1.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer and start debugging.
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }

        public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
        {
            if (composite == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
            }
            if (composite.BoolValue)
            {
                composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
            }
            Console.WriteLine(composite.StringValue + composite.BoolValue);
            return composite;
        }

        public List<AccountDto> GenerateMultipleAccounts(int count)
        {
            List<AccountDto> accounts = new List<AccountDto>();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                AccountDto newAccount = new AccountDto() { AccountId = Guid.NewGuid()};
                accounts.Add(newAccount);

            }
            return accounts;

        }
    }
}
```

Console Application

```
using developer1.Core;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using developer1.Core.Service;
using developer1.Core.Dto.Account;
using developer1.Core.ServiceContracts;
using AccountServiceClient = developer1.TestConsole.ServiceReference1.Service1Client;

namespace developer1.TestConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                AccountServiceClient AccountServiceClient = new AccountServiceClient();
                Guid testGuid = Guid.NewGuid();


List<AccountDto> newAccounts = new List<AccountDto>(AccountServiceClient.GenerateMultipleAccounts(2));
                Console.WriteLine(testGuid);
                CompositeType testDataContract = new CompositeType() { StringValue = "test", BoolValue = true };
                testDataContract = AccountServiceClient.GetDataUsingDataContract(testDataContract);
                Console.WriteLine(AccountServiceClient.GetData(6));
                Console.WriteLine(testDataContract.StringValue);
                //foreach (var item in newAccounts)
                //{

                //    Console.WriteLine(item.AccountId);
                //}

            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Data Contract

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Web;

namespace developer1.Core.Dto.Account
{
    [DataContract]
    public class AccountDto
    {
        [DataMember]
        public Guid AccountId { get; set; }
        //get { return this.AccountId; }
    //set { this.AccountId = this.AccountId == Guid.Empty ? Guid.NewGuid() : value; }

        [DataMember]
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string AccountName { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string BankName { get; set; }

        //get { return this.BankName; }
        //set { this.BankName = this.BankName == null ? "Unspecified" : value; }

}
}
```

ANSWER!!!!!!!

So I have solved this dreaded issue. You must create a WCF Service Library instead of a WCF Service Application. My god that is stupid that the application wont let you split your components outside of the interface.

Comment: Can you post the exception + stacktrace you get?

Comment: I noticed that there was not a serializable class called AccountDto generated within my reference.cs which may be causing the exception. I thought adding a service reference would auto generate this code for me.

Comment: Tried getting the stacktrace/inner exception but right after im returning accounts the application breaks. Seems to be due to the response coming back to the console application. can't figure out why.

Comment: is this resolved? I used exact code which you have given here and i get any error? Is the code that you are using is different?

Comment: Well seems the issue is resolved when i move the entire class out of its own cs file scoped under a Dto/Account directory and move it into the actual IService.cs file. Any ideas why this is happening? I want to be able to seperate Dto objects and have own files for them...encapsulation..instead of moving all my Data Contracts in the interface class.

Comment: So I have solved this dreaded issue. You must create a WCF Service Library instead of a WCF Service Application. My god that is stupid that the application wont let you split your components outside of the interface.

Comment: You can split components out the interface, it is just the fact that merging them fixed some other bug you had. Attach a debugger to the service while it is running and get a capture of the stack trace when it throws the stack overflow exception.

Comment: You can have both the service contracts (i.e., interfaces) and the DTOs in separate assemblies and still use the WCF Service Application project template.  We have over a dozen WCF services at work and this is the standard model we use (with a few special cases that are different).  You simply need to reference the other assemblies in the service project and use the correct `using` directives.

Comment: Well I tried restarting applications from scratch with the same error. Not sure why moving them into the interface fixes the issues. I made sure i was using the right using statements. However, now I am using the application to just launch the service and i have decoupled my Dto classes into their own project and the Service Contracts/Operation Contracts into their own projects under a service library. So i am using an application but, the svc file is just inheriting from the service class within a service library which is much better separation of concern

Comment: Not sure why the implementation of separating Dto classes is different between a service library and application but, the library worked right out of the box.